# ASP.NET MVC Core/6: EF 6 scaffolding error

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using `EF 6` with `MVC` Core/6. My models and db context are in separate project and I use DI to inject the db context into the controllers. But when I try to scaffold the controller using `EF 6` as the data context class I am getting the following error:

**Error**

> There was an error running the selected code generator: 
>       'A type with the name MyProject.DAL.ModeIs.MyModel does not exist 
>       Microsoft.VisuaIStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvokerb__6_0() 
>       Microsoft. Extensions.CommandLineUtiIs.CommandLineAppIication.Exe 
>       cute(String[] args) 
>       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.CodeGenCommand.Execu 
>       te(String[] args)'

Answer (score 2):

RC2 is the first release that somewhat allows you to include non-ASP.NET Core projects in your solution.  From my experience I've learned it only works if both projects were created in Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 and they both use .NET Framework 4.6.1.

There is a long running [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/45) about this.  I've struggled with the workarounds presented in that thread and couldn't waste anymore time messing with it.  So I decided to wait until a functional release comes out.  I put all my shared code in an ASP.NET Core (.NET Framework) project.  Made it look like a class library project by creating an empty project and deleting everything except project.json.  Then any functionality that is not supported in that stack, I put in a WebAPI 2 method that I can call from my RC2 project.

Answer (score 0):

This might be too late, however I had the same issue, I fixed it by adding to project.json:

```
"dependencies": {
  .....

    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
      "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
      "type": "build"
   .....
```

and

```
"tools": {
 .....
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    },
......
  },
```